# Beamer template with slide titles in bubbles

Tags: beamer, templates

I'm looking for a [`beamer`](//ctan.org/pkg/beamer) template which exactly matches [the following slides with the titles in bubbles](https://www.cse.cuhk.edu.hk/%7Etaoyf/course/infs4205/lec/rtree.pdf#page1). Can someone help me out?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `tcolorbox` package:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\normalsize}

\newtcbox{\mybox}{
  colframe=red!50!black,
  colback=red!10!white,
  arc=6pt,
  boxrule=1pt, 
  boxsep=0pt,
  left=6pt,
  right=6pt,
  top=2pt,
  bottom=2pt
}


\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\mybox{\insertframetitle}}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{some frame title}
    abc
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I benefit from this answer to check one thing with `tcolorbox`. As you notice "some frame title" has a different height vs "Example"... the "p" of example makes the `tcolorbox` look different, text looks less "centered". How can we avoid the difference of rendering in the boxes ?

Comment: @JeT You can make sure the text is always the same height with `\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\mybox{\insertframetitle\strut}}`